# Protype $$ in IE9

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, prototypejs, internet-explorer-9

I'm fairly new to prototype, but I'm experiencing some weird behaviour.

From what I understand using `$$('yourcssselector')` allows you to select multiple elements using a CSS selector. In FF, Chrome, Safari this all works fine.

However, in IE9 I'm getting undefined errors in my code using this.

What I've found is if you run this:

```
console.log($$('.btn1').size());
```

I get:

```
LOG: 1
```

But then if I run the exact same query again, I get

```
LOG: 0
```

In my code, this .btn1 is being called more than once with that sort of selector, so I'm wondering am I using this correctly, or is this a common IE bug?

Comment: Why are you calling size() twice?

Comment: `size` returns a number. It makes no sense to call `size` on the result of `size`.

Comment: Sorry, it was a typo when I was writing this. The issue is with $$('.btn1').size()

Comment: If page content wasn't changed between calls, $$() should always return the same result (using Prototype since 2008 in cross-browser environment, but didn't noticed such strange error). Any links to page with such error?